# Child states not rendering with parent state in Ionic V-1

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC0lu.png)I'm new to Ionic v-1. I tried implementing navigation using parent-child relationship. The parent state is "tab" while the active child state is "home". When I load the app, the home state contents do not load.

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs',{
      url:"/tab",
      abstract:true,
      templateUrl:"templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.addFriend',{
      url:"/addFriend",
      views:{
        'addFriend-tab':{
            templateUrl:"templates/addFriend.html",
            controller:'addFriendTabController'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.message',{
      url:"/message",
      views:{
        'message-tab':{
            templateUrl:"templates/message.html",
            controller:'messageTabController'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.notifications',{
      url:"/notifications",
      views:{
        'notifications-tab':{
            templateUrl:"templates/notifications.html",
            controller:'notificationsTabController'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.profile',{
      url:"/profile",
      views:{
        'profile-tab':{
            templateUrl:"templates/profile.html",
            controller:'profileTabController'
        }
      }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");
})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl',function($scope){
    console.log("Home tab");
})
.controller('addFriendTabController',function($scope){
    console.log("addFriend tab");
})
.controller('messageTabController',function($scope){
    console.log("message tab");
})
.controller('notificationsTabController',function($scope){
    console.log("notifications tab");
})
.controller('profileTabController',function($scope){
    console.log("profile tab");
});
```

```html
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <div class="bar bar-positive item-input-inset headerBorder">          
          <label class="item-input-wrapper positive-bg" id="headerSearch">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon searchIcon"></i>
            <input type="search" placeholder="People, jobs, posts and more...">
          </label>
          <a href="#"><i class="icon ion-grid placeholder-icon searchIcon"></i></a>
      </div>

      <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

      <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
          <div class="tabs-stripped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
            <div class="tabs tab-top">
              <a href="#/tab/home" class="tab-item active">
                <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#/tab/addFriend" class="tab-item">
                <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#/tab/message" class="tab-item">
                <i class="icon ion-chatboxes"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#/tab/notifications" class="tab-item">
                <i class="icon ion-android-notifications"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#/tab/profile" class="tab-item">
                <i class="icon ion-person"></i>
              </a>
            </div>  
          </div>   
      </script> 

      <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
          <ion-content class="has-tabs-top">
            <div class="list card">
              <div class="item item-thumbnail-left">           
                <img src="img/ionic.png">
                <h2 class="listCss">Name</h2>
                <h3>Followers</h3>
                <p>Time</p>          
              </div>
              <div class="item item-image">
                <img src="img/NIKHIL.jpg">
              </div>  
              <a href="#" class="item assertive">Click here...</a>
            </div>        
          </ion-content>
       </script>

       <script id="templates/addFriend.html" type="text/ng-template">

       </script>

       <script id="templates/message.html" type="text/ng-template">

       </script>

       <script id="templates/notifications.html" type="text/ng-template">

       </script>

       <script id="templates/profile.html" type="text/ng-template">

       </script>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use multiple named views you've to do like so for exmaple:

IN you HTML:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-bottom tabs-color-light tabs-background-brown">
    <ion-tab title="LAST SCAN" icon-off="fwd-last-scan-off" icon-on="fwd-last-scan-on" ui-sref="tab.lastscan">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-left"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="SCAN" icon-off="fwd-total-scan-off" icon-on="fwd-total-scan-on" ui-sref="tab.scan">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-center"></ion-nav-view>

    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="MENU" icon-off="fwd-menu-off" icon-on="fwd-menu-on" ui-sref="tab.menu">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-right"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="EXTRA" icon-off="fwd-extra-off" icon-on="fwd-extra-on">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-off"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

In your JS:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("gestione")
    .config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$ionicConfigProvider", "$httpProvider", "$ionicNativeTransitionsProvider",
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, $httpProvider, $ionicNativeTransitionsProvider) {



            // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/login");



            $stateProvider
                // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
                .state("tab", {
                    url: "/tab",
                    abstract: true,
                    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
                })

                // Each tab has its own nav history stack:
                .state("tab.lastscan", {
                    url: "/lastscan",
                    cache: false,
                    nativeTransitions: {
                        "type": "filp",
                        "direction": "up"
                    },
                    views: {
                        'tab-left': {
                            templateUrl: "templates/tab-lastscan.html",
                            controller: "LastScanCtrl",
                            controllerAs: "lastscan"
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state("tab.menu", {
                    url: "/menu",
                    views: {
                        'tab-right': {
                            templateUrl: "templates/tab-menu.html",
                            controller: "MenuCtrl"
                        }
                    }


          })
            .state("tab.settings", {
                url: "/settings",
                cache: false,
                views: {
                    'tab-off': {
                        templateUrl: "templates/settings.html",
                        controller: "SettingCtrl",
                        controllerAs: "settingCtrl"
                    }
                }
            })
          ;




    }]);
```

Comment: If it helped you and you want plz rate it.. thnx!!